# Send http header from wcf web service to android

Tags: c#, android, wcf

I am calling wcf rest service from android.suppose this is method i am calling.

```
    public Employee GetEmployee(int empId)
    {
        Employee emp = null;

        using (IDataReader reader = DataManager.ExecuteReaderProcedure(StoredProcedures.GetEmployee, empId))
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                emp = new Employee();
                emp.Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                emp.FullName = reader.GetString(1);
                emp.Designation = reader.GetString(2);
            }
        }

        return emp;
    }
```

Now i am not able to get how to send some information in http header from this method. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the WebOperationContext.

```
System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

**EDIT**

I have used `Cache-Control` as an example here you can specify any valid HTTP header.  The second parameter is the value you wish to set.

Comment: cache-control is key and no-cache is value . right?

Comment: appologies yes cache-control is the key I used it as an example you can set anything there (you should make sure its valid though)